# Is there any easy way to detect assertive, interrogative and other sentences

Tags: syntactic-analysis, parts-of-speech

I am looking for any specific series of rules or structures to detect assertive, interrogative and other sentences like wh-type question + subject + be verb + obj. etc.

Comment: In common English usage, assertive sentences have the main verb after the subject, and vice versa for interrogative sentences. But like everything related to language usage, there are exceptions. What other sentence types are you thinking of?

Comment: @ CJ SHEU
I am trying to make a database program where it will have the ability to recognize the sentence type and feedback based on that and also archive information from the lines if needed.

So,
after Searching a lot;
in case of interrogative; I've found few rules like:

Auxiliary verb+Subject.........?
Who/What+principal verb+obj...........?
WH word + Auxiliary verb+ Sub.+ principal verb+........?

I don't think identifying all of the subject will be pretty easy but it might be possible to identify others except objects. So, I am looking for these types actually . . .

Comment: Natural language processing is complicated. If you're not already very familiar with the language, I suspect you use 3rd-party tools instead of writing your own.

Comment: @ Barmar But I don't want to use 3rd-Party Tools like NLTK :(